# how do I configure etags/header on images

Tags: html, performance, image, caching, header

So I ran Google's pagespeed and Yslow on my site and one of their recommendations is to specify cache validators, ie headers such as Etag or Last-Modified...the question is...the files that they recommend doing so on are images....so how exactly am I supposed to add those headers onto images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could configure this on the folder level, depends on which web server you are using.
Possibly useful links:
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_11/

http://bytestopshere.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/disable-remove-etags-on-iis-6-to-improve-performance/